# Unable to do release build in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android-studio-2.3

I am getting the following error when i am trying to build my library module. This happened after I upgraded my studio to 2.3, before that it was working fine.

Error:Execution failed for task ':ABC:dexguardRelease'.

> Cannot cast object 'AndroidDependency{artifactFile=/Users/.../Library/../extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/25.1.0/design-25.1.0.aar, coordinates=com.android.support:design:25.1.0@aar, projectPath=null, extractedFolder=/Users/.../.android/build-cache/43e8b63934cde56d5e4203435db0b96a40055fac/output, variant=null, isSubModule=false, jarsRootFolder=/Users/.../.android/build-cache/43e8b63934cde56d5e4203435db0b96a40055fac/output/jars}' with class 'com.android.builder.dependency.level2.AndroidDependency' to class 'com.android.builder.model.AndroidLibrary'

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: No..i think it can be solved by upgrading dexguard. Not sure. But have to try it out.

Comment: have you tried upgrading, did it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by upgrading to dexguard version 8. Note that gradle 3.1+ will not detect your license file in same folder as the dexguard jar